# Renaming computer based using Powershell and CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, rename

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that creates a CSV from a specific OU, takes the last created computer (ie computer-200), adds 1 (so computer-201) and renames the computer. I was able to create the CSV but haven't been able to add an increment of 1 to the name.

Here is the script so far:

```
Add-WindowsCapability –online –Name “Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0”

$OUpath = 'OU=Computers,OU=Test-Devices,DC=Test,DC=local'
$ExportPath = 'c:\temp\computers_in_ou.csv'
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties whenCreated | select-object Name,whenCreated | sort whenCreated | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
$csvdata = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\computers_in_ou.csv'
$csvdata | Select-Object Name -Last 1 | Export-Csv -NoType 'c:\temp\renameWS.csv'
$name = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\renameWS.csv' | Select-Object Name -Last 1
```

The $name shows output of

Name: Computer-200

How can I take that 200 and add 1?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this the naming convention of the computers (always end with `-XXX` where `XXX` can be any amount of numeric digits) or the digits can be anywhere in it's name? Also, are you sure that `sort whenCreated` will always give you the computer with the highest numeric digit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use replacing [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) with a *script block* to increment the digits in the computer's name by 1:

For example:

```
[regex]::Replace('computer-200', '\d+', {
    param($s)
    [int] $n = $s.Value; (++ $n)
})

# Results in: `computer-201`
```

If you have access to PowerShell Core, [Replacement with a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block) was added in PowerShell 6 and later:

```
'computer-200' -replace '\d+', {
    $n = [int] $_.Value; (++ $n)
}
```

Following above examples, you could do the following to get the latest computer name and increment the digits by 1:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties whenCreated |
    Select-Object Name, whenCreated | Sort-Object whenCreated

[regex]::Replace($computers[-1].Name, '\d+', {
    param($s)
    [int] $n = $s.Value; (++ $n)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the exact format/trustworthiness of your CSV data, but here's a non-regex way to accomplish this using your existing code.

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\renameWS.csv'
$split = $csvdata[-1].name.Split('-')
$addOne = [int]$split[1] + 1
$final = $split[0] + '-' + $addOne
```

You can then take that $final string output and append to your CSV, rename with other cmdlets, etc.